# Facebook tab app using Dropbox Public Link (Link Error SOLVED)

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, dropbox, facebook-apps, public

Creating a [Facebook tab app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) using a Dropbox public link used to be simple, util Facebook made changes to it recently.

An unknown error **"There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."** will surface if you pump in the direct Dropbox link into the (Secure) Page Tab Url.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, you have to input into the *Page Tab Url* your Dropbox public link of the html file from

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/123456/foldername/index.html

to

> [https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/123456/foldername/index.html](http://www.example.com)

[image: Solution]

This is accurate as of August 2013. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I had this trouble recently, as mentioned by @George, you will have to edit the url link to your dropbox file. You will also have to point your canvas/secure canvas and page tab url to a directory by adding a "/" or to a string with "?" at the end.

You will need to change this:
https://**www.dropbox.com**/s/ak280yy2ey6ns/MY-FILE.html

to this:
https://**dl.dropboxusercontent.com**/s/ak280yy2ey6ns/MY-FILE.html**?**

correct as of 24th April 2014.

hope this helps :)
see my [Facebook Tab](https://www.facebook.com/teckstyle.co.uk/app/313348205484873/)

Comment: Hello @user3535811, are you still able to use this method now 15th Feb 2015?

Comment: yes, I have a few Facebook tabs/apps that call html from a Dropbox file... still working :)